# Different results for StereoBM on static image and video output

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I am currently working on a python project involving stereovision on a real time application to detect the environment and compute distances to obstacles.

I used tools from the StereoVision library as well as OpenCV's block matching functions (OpenCV 4.2.0).
I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 coupled with a stereovision hat which I calibrated beforehand.
I decided to go with StereoBM rather than StereoSGBM as it computes results much faster (despite lower quality results)
I used a tool provided with the StereoVision library to calibrate the parameters for the StereoBM algorithm.
This tool uses a single pair of rectified stereo images and computes the disparity map, using sliders to update said map and display results for the user to select appropriate pararmeters. When using this tool I get an output looking like so:
[StereoBM on static image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohQqC.jpg).

This result I'm satisfied with as, despite some small error patches, most elements have their depth computed properly.
However, when I try to use the same algorithm with saved parameters on a series of images provided by the camera video output (each image being treated independently one by one), I get a messed up result as shown (in color) on the next image:
[StereoBM on image from video output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H8R8.jpg).

I have tried recalibrating my camera, tweaking with the parameters etc... Nothing changes the quality of the output.
I don't understand why there is such a big difference between static image block matching and video output block so if anyone out there has a clue where it could come from, I would greatly appreciate.

Here are some bits of code from the python script that acquires the video output and computes the (bad) disparity map:

```
sbm = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=5)
sbm.setPreFilterSize(PFS)
sbm.setPreFilterCap(PFC)
sbm.setMinDisparity(MDS)
sbm.setNumDisparities(NOD)
sbm.setTextureThreshold(TTH)
sbm.setUniquenessRatio(UR)
sbm.setSpeckleRange(SR)
sbm.setSpeckleWindowSize(SPWS)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   #Both images from the stereo pair are acquired in the same frame
res_w = w
res_l = l
cap.set(3,res_w*2)
cap.set(4,res_l)
imgLeft, imgRight = IOutils.get_split_cam(cap,gray=False)   #Helper function to separate images left & right

sbmR = cv2.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(sbm)
wls_filter = get_WLSfilt(sbm)

dispL = sbm.compute(imgLeft, imgRight)
dispR = sbmR.compute(imgRight, imgLeft)
dispL = np.int16(dispL)
dispR = np.int16(dispR)
testL = cv2.applyColorMap(np.uint8(dispL), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
cv2.imshow("disp map", testL)
filteredDM = WLS.filter(dispL, imgLeft, None, dispR)   #Weighted Least Square filtering to improve output
filteredDM = trunc_n_scale(filteredDM)   #Helper function to truncate depth data and normalize it
filteredDM = np.uint8(filteredDM)

def get_WLSfilt(block_matcher, lmbda=8000, sigma=1.5):
    wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(matcher_left=block_matcher)
    wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
    wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)
    return wls_filter
```

Comment: The link to your Facebook group seems unnecessary. It could be confused for spam so I removed it

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't supposed to be a FB link, don't know why that happened.